# Unable to make requests by HttpClient nor fetch in NativeScript

Tags: angular, nativescript

I have NativeScript and Angular hybrid app. 
In NativeScript version some requests return errors, some works properly. 
On web projects all requests work's fine. 
How can I fix this requests to work properly on mobile app?

I've tried making requests by HttpClient and fetch, both methods failed.

Fetch method:

```
get() {
    fetch(this.url + '/data', {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
    }).then((r) => r.json())
        .then((response) => {
            console.log('res', response);
        }).catch((e) => {
            console.log('err', e);
        });
}
```

Fetch error: 
`TypeError: Network request failed: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream`

HttpClient method:

```
constructor(
    private http: HttpClient,
) {}

get(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get<any>(this.url + '/data',);
}
```

HttpClient error:

```
   "headers": {
     "normalizedNames": {},
     "lazyUpdate": null,
     "headers": {}
   },
   "status": 0,
   "statusText": "Unknown Error",
   "url": null,
   "ok": false,
   "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
   "message": "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error",
   "error": {
     "originalStack": "Error: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream\n    at new ZoneAwareError (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.ngsample/files/app/vendor.170597:33)\n    at onRequestComplete
    (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.ngsample/files/app/vendor.190367:34)\n    at Object.onComplete (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.ngsample/files/app/vendor.190356:13)",
     "zoneAwareStack": "Error: java.io.EOFException: Unexpected end of ZLIB input stream\n    at onRequestComplete (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.ngsample/files/app/vendor.190367:34) [<root>]\n    at Object.onComplete (file:///data/data/org.nativescript.ngsample/files/app/vendor.190356:13) [<root>]"
   }
}
```

Comment: Is `this.url` a HTTP or HTTPS endpoint? You may need to first set app-level permissions to allow communication with HTTP (non-secure) endpoints.

Comment: @JamieBirch it's HTTPS endpoint, also I have this permissions in AndroidManifest

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Comment: By default with any template `INTERNET` permission should be listed in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. If you are using http end point on Android 9 device for testing, http communication is disabled by default from Android 9. You can enable it by adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` on the `application` tag of your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: @Manoj I'm using https and I have `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in AndroidManifest

Comment: You would not need `usesCleartextTraffic` if it's https. Is it only that URL or you are unable to hit any url? Does it work on rest clients like POSTMAN? Is there any way you could share a Playground Sample?

Comment: I'm unable to hit only to this api, also some requests to this api works, some don't. I think it has somthing in common with response size.